# How to do insert another table with calculate value from another table using after insert in trigger mysql when i insert a specific value in a column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to mysql. How can I do after insert in trigger mysql?

```
table parent (gaji_bulanan) inserting from my sistem
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_gajibul|kd_gajibul|jenis_gaji|nip|massa|nama|bulan|tahun|upahperbulan|lem1|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1|KD.1|B|100|M1|enggar|oktober|2017|100000|1|
2|KD.2|B|100|M2|enggar|desember|2017|150000|2|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

the result is i wanted in another table (gaji_bulanan_b) from the trigger function like this

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_gajibul|kd_gajibul|jenis_gaji|nip|massa|nama|bulan|tahun|upahperbulan|lem1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3|KD.2|B||100|B|enggar|desember|2017|250000|3|
```

here is example my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `gaji`.`gaji_bul` AFTER INSERT
ON `gaji`.`gaji_bulanan`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.massa='M2' THEN
INSERT INTO gaji_bulanan_b(id_gajibul,kd_gajibul,jenis_gaji,nip,massa,nama,bulan,tahun,upah_per_bulan,lem1)
VALUES(NEW.id_gajibul,OLD.kd_gajibul,OLD.jenis_gaji,NEW.nip,NEW.massa='B',OLD.nama,NEW.bulan,NEW.tahun,
upah_per_bulan=NEW.upah_per_bulan+OLD.upah_per_bulan);
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: add your tables using the output from show create table. Add a few lines of sample data. And what exactly is the problem you have run into???

Comment: Your previous (duplicate?) question gave a better idea of what you are trying to achieve. You might be better restating the question with sample data and telling us what you have attempted. How by the way do you build your insert to `gaji`.`gaji_bulanan is this solely via mysql or is there something else in the mix such as php?

Comment: hi all, i have update example table value in my question. i'm sorry if confusing on you. assume i have done input into first value. and then when i have done to insert second value too (required massa='M2'). they calculate them self 'upahperbulan','lem1' in first value(M1) with 'upahperbulan','lem1' in second value(M2) where the id is still same and do it in once time.

i hope you understand what i mean.. :)